# fuelphp Composer is not installed. Please run "php composer.phar update" in the root to install Composer

Tags: php, php-5.3, fuelphp

I am trying to install fuelphp.

And getting the error as

```
Composer is not installed. Please run "php composer.phar update" in the root to install Composer
```

In my xampp/php directory I run a command

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

But once i run `php composer.phar install` composer could not find a composer.json in e:\xampp\php

How can i resolve and run fuelphp successfully can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.7.1, we no longer supply the composer.phar file in the zip. It only has a limited shelf life (30 days before it starts complaining).

Instead we suggest you install composer yourself, either locally (specific for this fuelphp installation) or globally so you only have to install it once for all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP, like npm for Node.js, bundler for ruby, and others.

It reads a file called composer.json with the dependent libraries your project needs and, finally, installs (downloads) them for you.

Fuelphp can be installed using composer, but there are several packages.

So, you need to create the composer.json with all needed fuelphp packages. Open notepad, save a file with the name composer.json (be sure to save it with ".json" extension) and put this content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "fuelphp/upload": "2.0.1",
        "fuelphp/event": "0.2.1",
        (...)
    }
}
```

Note you need to insert at "(...)" the others fuelphp packages and the needed versions. You can check them all at https://packagist.org/ (type fuelphp at search). Packagist is the main Composer repository.

More information about Composer at [this link](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Let me know if you need more information about it.

Comment: In which directory I have to save my composer.json. Whether in `xampp\htdocs\fuelphp` or in `xampp\php`

Comment: Save it at e:\xampp\php

Comment: "Composer is not installed" or "could not find a composer.json"? If is the second one, be sure you don't have "composer.json.txt" at file name (Windows can hide the txt extension), if is the first one, run 'php -r "eval(...' command again to download composer.phar.

Comment: This happens because is missing the composer.phar file (this is the file who reads the composer.json file and download the dependencies). Since I don't know if eval() will work for you, download composer in this link and save it at e:\xampp\php: http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41764/discussion-between-saulotoledo-and-editme-here)

Comment: Same error I think am doing some silly mistake I could not find it

Answer (score 0):

If you are running FuelPHP 1.7, the download comes with all Composer files you need. You need to run `php composer.phar install` in the root directory of FuelPHP (the same directory that contains the `public` folder and the `fuel` folder.

As long as you have v1.7 (I'm not sure if earlier versions contain the files), that directory will contain `composer.json` and `composer.phar`.

Answer (score 0):

In folder fuelphp-1.7 (latest), there are two files: composer.phar and composer.json you need to cd into that folder and run:

> php composer.phar install

If you don't have php in your path, you should do something like:

> e:\xampp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe composer.phar install

Use the full path to your php.exe. Remember your current working directory should be fuelphp folder where composer.phar and composer.json are.